# Nested loop to update recordset not working Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am planning to search and update records which matches my criteria in my table through a form.
I want my code to search for OrderNo and OrderNoItem ( For each orderno I have multiple OrderNoItems like 10,20,30... in my table) when there is a match I want to update the customer name(Text18.Value) from my Form.

I have the following code. For some reason it is just updating only the first record. For example when I input Text25.Value = 12345, Text27.Value = 20 and Text49.Value = 40, it is updating the customer name only for the rows with 12345 and 20. Can any one help??

```
Set logDB1 = CurrentDb()
Set logRS1 = logDB1.OpenRecordset("Log")   

For i = Text27.Value To Text49.Value Step 10
    Do Until logRS1.EOF
         If (logRS1![OrderNo] = Text25.Value And logRS1![OrderNoItem] = Text27.Value) Then
    
            logRS1.Edit
            logRS1![DTN-#] = Text18.Value
            logRS1.Update
          
         End If
    logRS1.MoveNext
    Loop
        
    Next
```

Comment: What is data structure? Why is customer name saved into Log table? Why do you even need to do this?

Comment: Are you saving customer name or a customer ID in [DTN-#]?

Comment: Customer ID but it is set as text field too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because code is set to do that. That's exactly what the If condition requires. What you should do is open the recordset filtered by OrderNo and the OrderNoItem range then just loop those records.

```
Set logDB1 = CurrentDb()
Set logRS1 = logDB1.OpenRecordset("SELECT [DTN-#] FROM Log WHERE OrderNo='" & _
                Me.Text25 & "' AND Val(OrderNoItem) BETWEEN " & Me.Text27 & " AND " & Me.Text49)   

    Do Until logRS1.EOF
        logRS1.Edit
        logRS1![DTN-#] = Me.Text18
        logRS1.Update
        logRS1.MoveNext
    Loop
```

Or instead of opening and looping recordset, Execute an UPDATE action SQL:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Log SET [DTN-#]='" & Me.Text18 & _
     "' WHERE OrderNo = '" & Me.Text25 & "' AND Val(OrderNoItem) BETWEEN " & Me.Text27 & " AND " & Me.Text49
```

If OrderNo is a number field, remove the apostrophe delimiters.

Strongly advise not to use punctuation/special characters (underscore is only exception) in naming convention. Better would be DTN_Num.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But I am getting Data type mismatch in criteria expression. I have OrderNo is Short Text field

Comment: The SQL is set up with OrderNo as a text field so that should not trigger error. What data types are [DTN-#] and OrderNoItem? Which code are you trying?

Comment: Both are set as Text fields

Comment: Numbers in a text field will not sort properly - 12 will sort before 2 because alpha sort rules apply. Therefore range criteria will fail. It can be handled (see revised answer) but why are these text fields?